# Detect when hard disk goes to sleep

Tags: windows, hard-drive, power-management, windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to trace when Windows turns off a hard disk (due to the power saving threshold being met)?

I'd like to see when (if at all) the disks are being turned off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [hdparm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm), a command line utility for getting/setting various HD parameters for IDE/SATA drives (DMA, IRQ, powermanagement etc.).

`hdparm -C <drive>` whill show the power state of the drive. You could run it periodically (e.g. from a BAT) to log HD state.

The Wikipedia article linked lists download sources for Linux and Windows.